# Unable to successfully update Wordpress admin password via MySql command line

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to change the admin password for my Wordpress site manually, by editing the **wp-config.php** and using the mySql command line(linux) as follows:

I change this line in wp-config.php in var/www/html/wordpress:

```
define('DB_PASSWORD','myNewPassword');
```

Then I update the wordpress database in mySql like this:

```
update wp_users set user_pass = md5('myNewPassword') where id = 1;
```

(I tried without the md5 as well, still doesn't work)

After verifying that the change was made, I close my browser, and then try to login to my wordpress site, but I keep getting this error:

> Error Establishing a Database Connection

When I change the password back to the old one, it works fine again.

Here are my version numbers:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 
wordpress Version 4.9.1
php version 5.6.14
mysql version 14.14 Distrib 5.6.36 for Linux(x86_64)
```

Are there any steps I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all: don't touch this line** `define('DB_PASSWORD','some_password');`. It's not users password, it's password to connect your `mysql` server.

The error you got `Error Establishing a Database Connection` occurred because of changing `constant`above.

From [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) sql command:

```
UPDATE (name-of-table-you-found) SET user_pass = MD5('(new-password)') WHERE ID = (id#-of-account-you-are-reseting-password-for);
```

So, your command will be:

```
//if your wordpress db tables prefix is `wp_`, then.
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = md5('myNewPassword') where id = 1;
```

If `database table prefix` is something else, then run command like:

```
UPDATE yourWebsitePrefix_users SET user_pass = md5('myNewPassword') where id = 1;
```

Also, make sure, that the password you're trying to change belong to the user with `id=1`. If your `user id` is, for ex. 27, then run this:

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = md5('myNewPassword') where id = 27;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another problem while updating the password through SQL query directly.

The problem is if you use a strong password including special characters, numbers and letters, then you will see the success message from MySQL but your login will not work.

```
update wp_users set user_pass = MD5('w9vAv>vCW(ux@!)--') where ID = 3;
```

In order to bypass this problem, I used a simple password like:

```
update wp_users set user_pass = MD5('mypassword') where ID = 3;
```

After using a simple password, I was able to log in with the new password.

I know this is risky but what I did immediately is as I logged in with a new password, I changed my login password inside the dashboard to a very strong password.